# Difference of 余 and 我

Tags: difference, word

余 and 我 both mean I. But I still can't understand the real difference. Also, I want an example sentence. When I use Google Translate and Bing Translator, the result is same.

Comment: 余 is from ancient Chinese, like `予/吾`. See wiki [汉语人称代词](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%B1%89%E8%AF%AD%E4%BA%BA%E7%A7%B0%E4%BB%A3%E8%AF%8D). And 我 is a modern style.

Comment: @Stan But I'm wonder, why 余 pronounce yu with second sound. But the 我 is pronounced wo with third sound

Comment: @ChristianIrwanHadiWicaksana Simply because they are two different characters.

Comment: Yu is right. Just like synonyms in English -- they don't have to be pronounced the same.

Comment: @Christian: Compare the normal Indonesian (or at least Malay) word for ‘I’, either _aku_ or _saya_, or the enclitic possessive form _-ku_. Those are the modern words, corresponding to 我 ‘I’ and 我的 and ‘my’ in Chinese. 余 would then correspond to the Classical Malay words for ‘I’ and ‘my’, which were apparently _kitta_ and _kitta poonea_, respectively—something I am guessing is completely incomprehensible to modern Indonesians.

Comment: 「余」（古輔音爲 *l-）和「吾/我」（古輔音爲 *ŋ-）的來源不同。在使用上的區別是，「余」作表所屬關係的定語時必須加「之」（如余之子），「吾/我」不加（如我子、吾子）。「我」是古漢語中延續下來的人稱代詞，並不是後起的。

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Stan said 余 is archaic and only found in literature. As in

```
余既为此志。——明· 归有光《项脊轩志》
```

我 is what modern-day Chinese use as the first-person pronoun.

```
我喜欢吃苹果。
```

I asked some Chinese friends and they only recognized 余 as a surname or meaning surplus or extra.

Comment: In traditional Chinese areas, 餘 is used *specially* for the meaning meaning surplus or extra. Though, 余 is also a traditional character and was used as an interchangeable character of 餘, today Hong Kong and Taiwan people use these two discriminatively.

Answer (score 1):

English also has ancient words, right? For example, English people used to use the word `thou` rather than `you`. It is the same in Chinese. 余 is the ancient word of 我.

Answer (score 0):

Practically, 余 is no long in use unless in poems or classic literature.

It would be more interesting to look at the various characters refer to 'I'.

我 is certainly the most widely used one.
咱 is colloquial.
俺 is more colloquial and vulgar.
阿拉 is commonly used in Shanghainese dialect.
吾 is in Cantonese dialect.

– and the list goes on.

Comment: 吾 is seldom heard in modern Cantonese. (Did you mean `唔(not)`?)

Comment: 吾系差人 means I am a police. Isn't it?

Comment: That's [我](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-can/search.php?q=%A7%DA) (ngo5), not [吾](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-can/search.php?q=%A7%5E) (ng4). See the links from 香港中文大學粵語審音配詞字庫 above. Now 吾 (as **I**) is hardly heard, because it sounds like 唔 and this would make people misunderstand a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

我 is also used in ancient times. For example, in 戰國策 之 鄒忌諷齊王納諫

> 鄒忌脩八尺有餘，而形貌昳麗。朝服衣冠，窺鏡，謂其妻曰：「我孰與城北徐公美？」其妻曰：「君美甚，徐公何能及君也。」城北徐公，齊國之美麗者也。忌不自信，而復問其妾曰：「吾孰與徐公美？」妾曰：「徐公何能及君也。」旦曰，客從外來，與坐談。問之曰：「吾與徐公孰美？」客曰：「徐公不若君之美也。」明日，徐公來，熟視之，自以為不如；窺鏡而自視，又弗如遠甚。暮寢而思之曰：「吾妻之美我者，私我也；妾之美我者，畏我也；客之美我者，欲有求於我也。」於是入朝見威王曰：「臣誠知不如徐公美。臣之妻私臣，臣之妾畏臣，臣之客欲有求於臣，皆以美於徐公。今齊，地方千里，百二時城。宮婦左右，莫不私王；朝廷之臣，莫不畏王；四境之內，莫不有求於王。由此觀之，王之蔽甚矣。」王曰：「善！」乃下令：「群臣吏民能面刺寡人之過者，受上賞；上書諫寡人者，受中賞；能謗議於市朝，聞寡人之耳者，受下賞。」令初下，群臣進諫，門庭若市；數月之後，時時而間進；諅年之後，雖欲言，無可進者。燕、趙、韓、魏聞之，皆朝於齊。此所謂戰勝於朝廷。

Answer (score 0):

Recent researches show that there are differences in grammatical forms of the 2 characters in ancient scripts before or in Qin Dynasty (approx. before 207 B.C.), but in later classical Chinese literature, they are synonyms.

In today's language, 余 as a pronoun has died and only can be seen when people try to **write** in classical Chinese.